# Robot Path Simulator

Tags: c, terminal

I'm pretty new to programming and all, and since we started using C recently, we had this task to create a program(robot simulator), on a hypothetical infinite grid of course, using only three possible movements: turn right,turn left and advance. The output need to be only x and y coordinates (x,y). Now the thing is, I can understand and make it only with all four movements(up,down,left,right - north,south,west,east (assuming that there is no turn left or turn right option,left means moving for 1 position to left,right means moving for 1 position to right etc.)). So just a simple subtraction between them gives me the final coordinates but I simply don't know how to make a rule for the ones with 2 turn options and advance. I'll leave my code for the task I already did so If anyone thinks that I can upgrade that one or has any advice or idea on how to make it work please let me know.

```
#include<stdio.h> 
static void position(int n, char* string)
{
    int left = 0, right = 0, up = 0, down = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (string[i] == 'L')
            left++;
        else if (string[i] == 'R')
            right++;
        else if (string[i] == 'U')
            up++;
        else if (string[i] == 'D')
            down++;
    }
    printf("(%d,%d)", (right - left), (up - down));
}
int main()
{
    printf("Enter your movement: ");
    char string[1000];
    scanf("%s", string);
    int n;
    for (n = 0; string[n] != '\0'; ++n);
    string[100] = string[n];
    position(n, string);
}
```

Comment: C# is not C++ is not C. They're not the same language just because they start with the same letter, any more than a caterpillar, a car and a carrot are the same. Please use only the tag for the language you're actually using. Tag spamming is an excellent way to get your question closed and downvoted. You should spend some time taking the [tour] and reading the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you start posting.

Comment: I don't think the intention is for you to just call `position` once. Your code needs to keep track of the current position and the `position` function needs to update the current position for repeated inputs. Then you just need to work out what the mathematical operation for each operation is. For example: depending on how left is defined it might be left(x,y)=(x,y-1). Then you need to deal with boundary conditions.

Comment: Please provide sets of sample input and desired output.

Comment: I do not understand this part, please explain a little more: "So just a simple subtraction between them gives me the final coordinates".

Comment: I miss information on the initial heading. Can we assume that the robot initially faces north/up? That would mean the a first command of "advance" gets the robot to (0,1), another "advance" to (0,2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to solve this is with a Cartesian coordinate system.

[image]

Rather than try and calculate everything at the end, I just track the movements as they are processed.

```
#include<stdio.h> 

enum {NORTH/*UP*/,SOUTH/*DOWN*/, EAST/*LEFT*/, WEST/*RIGHT*/};
static void position(int n, char* string)
{                           // let's use a Cartesian coordinate system
    // assume a 10x10 grid
    int X=0,Y=0;            // start at this place within the grid (the center)
    int direction = NORTH;  // we are facing NORTH
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (string[i] == 'L') // TURN LEFT, no step
        {   // pivot
            switch (direction)
            {
            case NORTH: 
                direction = EAST;   // face EAST, but do not step
                break;
            case SOUTH: 
                direction = WEST;   // face WEST, but do not step
                break;
            case EAST: 
                direction = SOUTH;  // face SOUTH, but do not step
                break;
            case WEST: 
                direction = NORTH;  // face NORTH, but do not step
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (string[i] == 'R') // TURN RIGHT, no step
        {   // pivot
            switch (direction)
            {
            case NORTH: 
                direction = WEST;   // face WEST, but do not step
                break;
            case SOUTH: 
                direction = EAST;   // face EAST, but do not step
                break;
            case EAST: 
                direction = NORTH;  // face NORTH, but do not step
                break;
            case WEST: 
                direction = SOUTH;  // face SOUTH, but do not step
                break;
            }
        }
        else if (string[i] == 'A')
        {   // advance
            switch (direction)
            {
            case NORTH: 
                if (Y == 5)
                    printf("you cannot go NORTH any more.\n");
                else
                    Y++;
                break;
            case SOUTH: 
                if (Y == -5)
                    printf("you cannot go SOUTH any more.\n");
                else
                    Y--;
                break;
            case EAST: 
                if (X == -5)
                    printf("you cannot go EAST any more.\n");
                else
                    X--;
                break;
            case WEST: 
                if (X == 5)
                    printf("you cannot go WEST any more.\n");
                else
                    X++;
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%c is not a valid command.\n", string[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("(%d,%d)", X, Y);
}
int main()
{
    char string[1000];
    int n;
    for(;;)
    {   // only valid movements are turn Right,turn Left and Advance. (RLA)
        printf("Enter your movement: ");
        scanf("%s", string);
        for (n = 0; string[n] != '\0'; ++n);
        string[100] = string[n];
        position(n, string);
    }
}
```

Sample I/O

Enter your movement: @

@ is not a valid command.

(0,0)

Enter your movement: LLLA

(1,0)

Enter your movement: LLLA

(1,0)

Enter your movement: LLLAAA

(3,0)

Enter your movement: LLARRRAA

(2,-1)

Enter your movement: LRLRLRA

(0,1)

Comment: Don't you agree that OP is asking about NOT using "UDRL" anymore?

Comment: @Yunnosch perhaps. In my example, you can replace UP/DOWN etc. with N,S,E,W, NE, SE, NW, SW. Although the diagonals would need to be implemented. Then we need to define 'TURN RIGHT" If TURN RIGHT literally means 'TURN', If this is the case, then we need to include a direction we're traveling flag. So basically if you're heading up and you turn right then you are say proceeding West, if you then turn right again you are now proceeding South. Right again and you're now proceeding East. Those cases can be added to my above code, without too much trouble.

Comment: Yes, that is what I am pretty sure OP is asking about. Name changes for semantically the same compass directions is irrelevant. The "relative" direction concept is the needed change. But without any feedback by OP, the discussion is moot. I am afraid your valiantly spent effort is lost on an asker like this...

Comment: @Yunnosch, Okay, well it was a fun exercise ;) 
I've updated my example to be what I *think* the OP is asking for. each of L and R simply pivots the *direction* the robot is facing - without taking a step. The A(advance) then moves the robot one step (if possible,) in that direction.

Comment: I hope I did not spoil anything for you. But actually you are now in the comfortable position of having the answering monopole on this question. ;-)

Comment: Reading your output, I wonder why after the second "LLLA", the position does not change. Do you start each time from (0,0, facing north)? That'd match. Am I reading something wrong?

Comment: Everything is reset once we return to main.
Easy to carry over the values, but I think this is why the OP had us pass in a string of positions. *shrugs*

Comment: Quite probable. I wish this question would be improved. I itch to also try my hand.